# Facebook API: Can it access "notes"?

Tags: php, facebook

Before I pursue this, I would first like to know if it's possible. So, does anyone know if I can do this with the facebook Api:

- Access the "notes" application
- Retrieve the text in the note
- Retrieve the comments written on the note
- Retrieve the details (username and ID) of the person who wrote the note

Anyone?

Comment: The OP followed up asking specifically about retrieving comments written in notes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284641/facebook-getting-comments-of-notes/2787855#2787855)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bullets 1, 2, and 4 are possible through [Notes.get](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Notes.get).  Bullet 3 might be possible through [Stream.getComments](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.getComments) (you should experiment with this yourself to be sure it is).

Comment: i just started fiddling around with stream.GetComments... and I think I might be onto something. :) Thanks so much!

Comment: @RD: When someone provides a suggestion and you try it, please post whether you were able to get it working or not