# Facebook: Getting comments of notes

Tags: facebook

You can get notes using **notes_get**. And you get comments using **comments_get** if you know the id of the comment.

But how do you get all the comments of a note? or, actually, how do you get a list of all the comment id's posted to a note?

Answer (score 1):

maybe the code in [Facebook Comments](https://svn.wp-plugins.org/facebook-comments/tags/0.21/facebooknotes.php) can help?

Comment: This thing is soooo outdated. Tried it a while back, and I'm effectively trying to write a module like this but for Drupal and using the API.

Comment: They parse the actual HTML, rather than using the API. That approach would work, but you would have to try to constantly keep up with Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Facebook Graph API section on [notes](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/note), I can see that there is a comments connection. Unfortunately, clicking on it provided a blank data structure. Perhaps it will be supported in the future? Looking [elsewhere](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing), it seems to be possible to comment on a "post". I don't know whether or not that includes notes? I would really like to be able to do this too, so that I could have two way sync between Wordpress and Facebook. Notably, the iPhone Facebook app doesn't support comments on notes. If it did, we would have an API that would have to be reasonably stable as otherwise they'd break their own app.